# How can I add a COM DLL reference in my .NET Core project based on beta8?

Tags: .net-core, dll, com

We have a .NET Core web project based on version dnx 1.0.0-beta8. I am trying to reference a COM DLL which I have to register on the computer through regsvr32. Do .NET Core projects allow you to reference COM DLLs?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a beta version when the release version of .NET Core has been released?

Comment: We are in the middle of moving the application to another framework based on Java. Hence, did not upgrade to a stable version.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge all currently released versions of .NET Core (1.1 and below) and .NET Standard (1.6 and below) do not have a way to add COM references due to the fact that .NET Core is designed to be multi-platform and COM is a Windows-specific feature.

I do not know if 2.0 will bring this feature in or not.

Comment: It is actually possible, but not simple.  First hangup is the type library importer, needs to be worked around by running the framework version of it, using ildasm.exe to decompile the interop assembly and replace the assembly reference for mscorlib to System.Runtime (.publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A), .ver 4:1:0:0), put back together with ilasm.exe.  Edit the project file to add the `<Reference>`.  Pinvoke CoInitializeEx() to initialize COM before making any calls.  Seems to work just fine.